# Why is the multiple select form_for making my form return nil in rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

My slim template looks like this:

```
= form_for @user_event do |f|
  .field
      = f.select :invited, @friendsArray, {}, { :multiple => true }
  .actions = f.submit 'Save'

@friendsArray example = [["John Nash", "8360775"], ["Jonathan Baldy", "30880087"], ["David Gray", "39900933"]]
```

When I remove `{ :multiple => true }` it submits an id for the chosen name.

When I add `{ :multiple => true }` I want it to submit multiple id's but it just returns {} for the user_event_params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must permit an array [] in your controllers params method.

In the user_events_controller.rb I now have

`def user_event_params
   params.require(:user_event).permit(invited: [])
 end`

You then may get an error as your database probably won't allow you to save an array to it.

This can be fixed my adding `serialize :invited` to your model, in my case user_event.rb. This  is cool because when you retrieve the attribute from the db in turns it from a string back to an array.